# What is the correct way to use CascadeType.MERGE with Spring Data Repositories?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373383/jpa-onetoone-difference-between-cascade-merge-and-persist) committing the transaction that saves the instances of `entity2` and `entity3`, which each hold a reference to an Entity1 (entity1) instance, results in two records of entity1 appearing in the database (Since the reference is saved when each of the instances are saved).

If I have 2 Spring Data Repositories - `Entity2Repository` and `Entity3Repository` and I do the following will that result in 2 instances of entity 1 being contained in the database:

```
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
entity1.name = "Name1";
entity1.value = "Value1";

Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2();
entity2.name = "Name2";
entity2.value = "Value2";
entity2.setEntity1(entity1);

Entity3 entity3 = new Entity3();
entity3.name = "Name3";
entity3.value = "Value3";
entity3.setEntity1(entity1);

Entity2Repository.save(entity2);
Entity3Repository.save(entity3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

It will work correctly (only produce one record of `entity1`).

#### Long answer

The actual result of the sample code execution depends on the [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation presence on your test method.

```
Entity2Repository.save(entity2);
Entity3Repository.save(entity3);
```

These calls will invoke the [SimpleJpaRepository#save()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html#save-S-) method, which is @Transactional itself.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Also, as you see, you should not worry about persist/merge calls - if it's a *new* entity, `persist()` will be called. `isNew()` check is pretty simple (see [AbstractPersistable](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html) source code):

```
public boolean isNew() {
    return null == getId();
}
```

**Without @Transactional**

There will be two transactions - one for each `save()` call.

- `entity1`, `entity2` and `entity3` are **TRANSIENT** now
- `Entity2Repository.save(entity2)` is invoked
- Transaction is opened, Session is created

  - `persist()` is invoked for `entity2`, as it's new entity
  - `persist()` is cascaded to `entity1`
  - `entity1` and `entity2` are **PERSISTENT** now, they are attached to the 
    current Session
- Transaction is commited, Session is closed
- `entity1` and `entity2` are **DETACHED** now
- `Entity3Repository.save(entity3)` is invoked
- Transaction is opened, Session is created

  - `persist()` is invoked for `entity3`, as it's new entity
  - `persist()` is cascaded to `entity1`
  - `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist` is thrown
- Transaction is rolled back, Session is closed

`entity1` and `entity2` entries are saved in the database.

**With @Transactional**

As default @Transactional propagation is [`REQUIRED`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) - there will be only one transaction.

- `entity1`, `entity2` and `entity3` are **TRANSIENT** now
- Transaction is opened, Session is created

  - `Entity2Repository.save(entity2)` is invoked
  - `persist()` is invoked for `entity2`, as it's new entity
  - `persist()` is cascaded to `entity1`
  - `entity1` and `entity2` are **PERSISTENT** now, they are attached to the current Session
  - `Entity3Repository.save(entity3)` is invoked
  - `persist()` is invoked for `entity3`, as it's new entity
  - `persist()` is cascaded to `entity1`, managed entity found in the first-level cache
  - `entity3` is **PERSISTENT** now, it is attached to the current Session
- Transaction is commited, Session is closed

`entity1`, `entity2` and `entity3` entries are saved in the database.