# when is the ID (GenerationType.SEQUENCE) set in the object?

Tags: database, jpa, oracle11g, sequence

I would like to know at what time exactly the Id of an object is set to the next value of a sequence declared in (oracle) database.

Here is the code :

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_A")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_A", sequenceName = "SEQ_A_ID")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When does the JPA set a @GeneratedValue @Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087848/when-does-the-jpa-set-a-generatedvalue-id)

Answer (score 2):

When having a sequence, JPA sets the id exactly after you call the persist method of your EntityManager instance. There is no need to commit of flush. The id is available exactly after that call.
That's the main difference between GenerationType.SEQUENCE and .IDENTITY. The later one offers the id after contacting the db, while SEQUENCE sets it directly, because a group of ids is preloaded in the application at runtime, therefore there's no need to interact with the db for getting an id.

Explanation of JPA protocol by a different implementation:
"Unlike AUTO and IDENTITY, the SEQUENCE strategy generates an automatic value as soon as a new entity object is persisted (i.e. before commit). This may be useful when the primary key value is needed earlier. To minimize round trips to the database server, IDs are allocated in groups. The number of IDs in each allocation is specified by the allocationSize attribute. It is possible that some of the IDs in a given allocation will not be used. Therefore, this strategy does not guarantee there will be no gaps in sequence values."
http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated