# How to test EntityManager.persist() invocation

Tags: java, spring, configuration, transactions, spring-transactions

I've got a simple test in Spring Container:

```
public class JpaCategoryRepositoryTest extends AbstractJpaJavaTestBase {

    @Inject
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Test
    public void testStoreCategory(){
        final Category category = new CategoryBuilder()
                .name("Test category")
                .build();
        assertEquals("Cateogory ID is not assigned", 0L, category.getId());
        categoryService.storeCategory(category);
        assertNotEquals("Category ID is persistent", 0L, category.getId());
    }
}
```

The `assertNotEquals` fails. I thought that transaction has not been committed yet. Ok, I've updated the test adding transactio management:

```
public class JpaCategoryRepositoryTest extends AbstractJpaJavaTestBase {

    @Inject
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Inject
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testStoreCategory(){
        final Category category = new CategoryBuilder()
                .name("Test category")
                .build();
        assertEquals("Cateogory ID is not assigned", 0L, category.getId());
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                categoryService.storeCategory(category);
                return null;
            }
        });
        assertNotEquals("Category ID is persistent", 0L, category.getId());
    }
}
```

But it did not help. 
What's the best pattern to test that an entity has been saved during integration tests? The actual entity is saved, when I check the table after the test fails.

Answer (score 3):

In the JPA specification it is left up to the JPA implementation when exactly the ID of the entity is set. It must however be set when the entity is written to the database. You can force this by calling entityManager.flush(). So adding an entityManager to your test:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and calling flush() after storing the entity:

```
categoryService.storeCategory(category);
entityManager.flush();
```

should fix your test.

See also: [When does the JPA set a @GeneratedValue @Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087848/when-does-the-jpa-set-a-generatedvalue-id)

Comment: Flushing means that sql queries are run to the database. If I undestand correclty, the same is archived when I used TransactionTemplate explicitly. So I don't see any difference. Anyway, I tried your solution, but I got the exception: "Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels - use a special JpaDialect for your JPA implementation"

Comment: The only way to get an ID in your entity is to get the ID from the database. So if you want to verify that an ID is set you will need to run the queries against the database (could also be an in-memory database). The exception is a known issue when you change the isolation level in your configuration, specifically in unit tests: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5012

Comment: It seems you don't understand what you are talking about. First you reccomend to flush it. Then you say that the only way to get ID is to run query. Next you give me a link to exception solution, but I don't set a specific isolation level per transaction.

Comment: I mean that by flushing you force the (update) queries that have not yet been communicated to the databse will be communicated to the database. This will result in setting the ID field of your entity. You can however still choose to rollback or commit the transaction. The isolation level exception is unclear to me. It could be caused by your Spring or persistence.xml configuration you are using for the unit test.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I could not find solution to get ID of the entity that has just been persisted. It may depend on id generation strategy, jpa provider, etc.

In order to test that the entity is persisted I'm checking the number or records before the test and after the transaction commit. The test now looks like:

```
@Inject
private CategoryService categoryService;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Test
public void testStoreCategory(){
    final Category category = new CategoryBuilder()
            .name("Test category")
            .build();
    assertEquals("The number of test categories loaded during initial setup is incorrect",
            1, entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c").getResultList().size());
    assertEquals("Cateogory ID is not assigned", 0L, category.getId());
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            categoryService.storeCategory(category);
        }
    });
    assertEquals("The test category has not been persisted",
            2, entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c").getResultList().size());
}
```