# Get Id of the associated object after save

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is simple model of associated entities:

MainModel class

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "main_model")
public class MainModel 
{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_main_model", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<AssociatedModel> am_collection;

    public MainModel() { }

    public long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void addAssociated(AssociatedModel am)
    {
        am_collection.add(am);
    }
}
```

AssociatedModel class

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "associated_model")
public class AssociatedModel
{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;

    public AssociatedModel() { }

    public long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Simplest jpa repository for MainModel

```
public interface MainModelDAO extends JpaRepository<MainModel, Long>  
{
}
```

and finally, controller's method for creating and saving AssociatedModel instance

```
@RequestMapping("/url")
public String createAssociated(@RequestParam("id_mainmodel") long id_mainmodel, @RequestBody AssociatedModel newAm) 
{
    MainModel mm = MainModelDAOobject.findOne(id_mainmodel);// MainModelDAOobject - @Autowired
    mm.addAssociated(newAm);
    MainModelDAOobject.saveAndFlush(mm);
    return String.valueOf(newAm.getId());// get Id of associated saved object
}
```

Associated obect saves into database correctly, but **id** value of this object, allowed by its `getId()` method, always **zero**. How can I get Id of the saved associated object correctly?

Comment: this will not solve your problem, but spring-data is pretty cool! have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `MainModelDAOobject.flush()` after saving the value, but before reading the ID.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088144/1464763) for an explanation.

**Edit**: try manually saving `newAm` by adding a new line:

```
mm.addAssociated(newAm); // Existing line
newAm = MainModelDAOobject.save(newAm); // New line
MainModelDAOobject.save(mm); // Existing line
```

Comment: This is not clear for me. I'm not use EntityManager.

Comment: Ok, I assume you're using Spring Data JPA then? Edited my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spring Data JPA and I tried MainModelDAO.flush() - this has no effect

Comment: Yes, I did both: mm = MainModelDAOobject.save(mm); MainModelDAOobject.flush();

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think. See my last edit. This is my last try before I give up!

Comment: This can't be done, because repository parameterized by MainModel - JpaRepository<MainModel, Long>

Answer (score 0):

you need a sequencegenerator:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MainModel SequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MainModel SequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "MainModel Sequence", initialValue = SEQUENCE_INITIAL_VALUE, allocationSize = SEQUENCE_ALLOCATION_SIZE)
```

Comment: Ids for the created records generates correctly in the database. I just cant get them after save.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to **David Levesque** for helpful suggestion.

problem is solved as follows:

1. need additional repository for AssotiatedModel

   public interface AssotiatedModelDAO extends JpaRepository  {}
2. then just save associated object manually:

   mm.addAssociated(newAm);

   newAm = AssotiatedModelDAOobject.save(newAm);

   newAm = MainModelDAOobject.save(newAm)`;

   MainModelDAOobject.save(mm);