# No part of a composite indentifier may be null

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make a **composite primary key mapping** and doesn't work.

**The requisites are:**

- The relation may be with `@IdClass` annotation
- I need the relationship with person entity be `@ManyToOne`

**My code:**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PhonePK.class)
public class Phone implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "codigo", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long code;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person", referencedColumnName = "code", nullable = false)
    private Person person;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
    private Integer number;

    //getters and setters
    //equals and hashcode
}

public class PhonePK implements Serializable {
    private Long code;
    private Long person;

    public PhonePK(){}

    public PhonePK(Long code, Long person) {
        this.code = code;
        this.person = person;
    }

    //getters and setters
    //equals and hashcode
}

public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false)
    private Long code;

    //getters and setters
    //equals and hashcode
}
```

**They way I'm trying to persist:**

```
//a lot of code
//em = Entitymanager
em.persist(person);
phone.setPerson(person);
em.persist(phone);
```

**The error that I'm receiving is:**

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null

Comment: Ho the key is specified in your phone? em.persist(phone); Looks like one of code or person is null in the PhonePK (or the PhonePK is null)

Comment: I'm persisting a new person and then persisting a new phone. All the pks are null at start

Comment: The error message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: But, doesn't Hibernate set the IDs???? How can be null?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an issue in [hibernate.atlassian](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6044). I gave up the composite key and just put a foreign key from `Person` in `Phone`.

Comment: I would have been helpful to show an example of how you did the mapping differently to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a high chance that the Person you are setting on the Phone entity doesn't have and ID yet. Persist doesn't garante and ID. It is recommended you also flush the transaction.

Related: [ID not added on persis()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9088144/5047727)

Comment: I flushed and getting the error too.... I'm not setting the ID in phone cause is Generated... but can I use generated in composite?