# Hibernate @ManyToOne of an entity with @IdClass

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I just added a new entity to my project and now it doesn't start.
I think it is related to having a `@ManyToOne` being part of a composite key but I'm not sure.
I reduced my problem to the following entities:

**A.class:**

```java
@Table(name = "A")
@Entity
@IdClass(KeyA.class)
public class A {
    
   @Id
   private String aId;
    
   @Id
   @ManyToOne
   private B b;
    
   public String getaId() {
      return aId;
   }
    
   public void setaId(String aId) {
      this.aId = aId;
   }
    
   public B getB() {
      return b;
   }
    
   public void setB(B b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```

**B.class:**

```java
@Table(name = "B")
@Entity
@IdClass(KeyB.class)
public class B {
    
   @Id
   String bId;
    
   @Id
   String bId2;
    
   public String getbId() {
      return bId;
   }
    
   public void setbId(String bId) {
      this.bId = bId;
   }
    
   public String getbId2() {
      return bId2;
   }
    
   public void setbId2(String bId2) {
      this.bId2 = bId2;
   }
}
```

**KeyA.class:**

```java
public class KeyA implements Serializable {
    
   private String aId;
   private String b;
}
```

**KeyB.class**

```java
public class KeyB implements Serializable{
    
   public String bId;
   public String bId2;
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
        Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
        [...]
        Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    [...]
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate field name [bId] on class [java.lang.String]
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findField(ReflectHelper.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessFieldImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessFieldImpl.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.java:26) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
```

I tried everything, including importing latest javassist.
I'm running Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE on Java 1.8 (it also happens in 11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use in your `KeyA` exactly the same fields name/types as marked in the owned entity as `@Id`.

So, you should correct `KeyA` in the following way:

```java
public class KeyA implements Serializable {

    private String aId;
    private B b;
}
```

See further explanation and examples in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated).

Comment: I see, to indicate a composite key of a composite key you need that. Thank you!

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí I have updated the answer,  it looks like Smutje answer can be corrected to be workable.

Comment: It is strange, I'll recheck it, it maybe a hibernate bug.

Comment: Do you join `B`  by both columns in the `KeyB` ?

Comment: Actually, the second approach works BETTER as it fixed this bug ocurring when retrieving the entity eith childs for the first time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521486/no-part-of-a-composite-indentifier-may-be-null

Comment: I have removed it, but it will be interesting further investigate it

Answer (score 3):

Your composite key of `A`

```
public class KeyA implements Serializable {

    private String aId;
    private String b;
}
```

is structured as if `B` would have only a single string ID (here referred to as `b`) while in reality it has a composite key itself

```
public class KeyB implements Serializable{

    public String bId;
    public String bId2;
}
```

so you have to change `KeyA` to represent that relationship correctly:

```
public class KeyA implements Serializable {

    private String aId;
    private KeyB keyB;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is correct but instead the KeyB it shoud be the B entity itself.

Comment: No, that is only valid if your entity has not a composite PK

Comment: I just tested It both ways and it only worked with "private B b;"

Comment: Interesting, I am pretty sure I did the same a few years back and it only worked with the IdClass references on the PK level

Comment: I only found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385658/jpa-how-to-make-composite-foreign-key-part-of-composite-primary-key but they are using EmbeddedId there