# EJB/JPA: After persisting an entity object, its getId() returns 0 - even though it's been correctly stored in the table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

This is a simplified, and hopefully clearer version of a question I asked

EDIT: I'm working in NetBeans, persistence provider is Hibernate, here is an image of the actual Database tables (in response to @xiumeteo):

[image]

Basically, my problem is that I auto-generate ID values when I persist an entity, and even though the entities are correctly saved into the database, with a correct ID > 0, the entityManager always seems to think that the now persisted entity has an ID of 0. Which leads to subsequent violations of foreign key constraints, but here I’ll just focus on the Id being (or rather, posing as) 0, because that should be closely related to the cause of the problem, and it's in fact a mystery in and of itself.

So I have a simple entity class Person:

```
    @Entity
    public class Person {

       @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private Long id;  // I’ve also tried types Integer and int, doesn’t make a difference.

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String email;
        public Person() {
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

    // setters and getters for the other fields omitted here.
    }
```

Then I have a session bean, containing a method create(p) that persists a person-object p:

```
  @Stateless
    @Default
    public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepository {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional  // Deleting this annotation makes no difference, only added 
                       it because I  thought it might solve the problem...
    public Person create(Person p) {
        entityManager.persist(p);
        entityManager.flush();   // Again, only added this statement because I thought it  
                                    might solve the issue, which it did not.
        return p;
        }
    }
```

Now in and of itself, the create(p) method does what it’s supposed to do: it persists the person p into the PERSON-table, with a correctly generated ID.

However, the problem becomes obvious when I try to get the value of that ID ***after*** the person-object has been persisted; it’s still given as being 0. So I call the create(p) method from a servlet, then immediately get the persisted object’s ID and have it print out to the console, like this (note: personRepo is an injected instance of the session bean whose definition is found above):

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Carl"); p.setEmail(carl@carl.nl); 
p = personRepo.create(p); // Everything going fine here => entity p gets stored 
                             in the PERSON table with a correctly generated ID>0.    
System.out.println("The newly persisted entity now has the following ID: " + p.getId());
```

And that last println-statement ALWAYS prints 0 as the value of p.getId(), whereas I want it to print the ID-value of the table-row corresponding to the entity.

In answers to similar questions, I’ve read that a call to flush() should help (which is why I added it to the above create-method), but clearly in my case it does not. As seen above, even after returning from the create() method (which does the actual persisting) to the calling servlet, the Id-field is still given as having a value of 0. Even though, as I said, it IS at that point stored in the database-table PERSON with a correct ID>0.

So how do I get the getId() function to return the REAL id? 
(And by extension, hopefully, get the entityManager / container to 'see' the real id-value as well, so that the entity can engage in many-to-many relationships without violating FK-constraints.)

Comment: which db are you using for this example?

Comment: The persistence provider is Hibernate. The actual databases are JavaDB / Derby (see newly attached image in the Question itself.

Comment: That was in response to @xiumeteo...

Comment: Just to not let you in the dark hehe. I made a research and found something about not all drivers/db supporting the automagically refresh of the id with IDENTITY GenerationType. I´m still looking for your particular case tho.

Comment: did you try using AUTO instead of identity? @Holland

Comment: KInd of relate with this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087848/when-does-the-jpa-set-a-generatedvalue-id#comment37670804_9088144

Comment: have you try using `entityManager.save(p)` instead of `entityManager.persist(p)`?

Comment: @xiumeteo Thanks, will try using AUTO later this weekend.

Comment: And yes, I'd seen that other question and its answers as well, but still couldn't get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `session.save(p)` instead of `entityManager.persist(p)`. `save()` will returns an identifier, and if an INSERT has to be executed to get the identifier, this INSERT happens immediately.

OR

Try refresh your entity after flush, to re-read that entity state.

```
entityManager.persist(p);
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.refresh(p);
```

Comment: There is no `entityManager.save(p)` in the JPA API!